# Play sound in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'd like to play .mp3 or wav sounds in my uwp app, I need to play it only when app is open and without any media element on the ui. Is there a possibility to make some threads to play separate songs at the same time. Any relevant info is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapting the above answer slightly using `MediaElement`. Presumes you have a media file at the root of your application in `MyFolder/MySound.wav`

```
 var element = new MediaElement();
 var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
 var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("MySound.wav");
 var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
 element.SetSource(stream, "");
 element.Play();
```

Comment: does it work with multiple sounds at the same time? Like a SoundPool in Android - just manage how many sounds can play at the same time, the priority and if it can perform any memory leaks to my app?  In official doc I didn't see any relevant info about this.

Comment: just had a look at `SoundPool` docs and `MediaElement` seems to be missing some of the priority/multiple track features of SoundPool. Think it only plays one track at a time you may have to load up multiple MediaElements although will probably result in a memory hit

Answer (score 3):

May be this code snippet will help you out.

```
MediaElement PlayMusic = new MediaElement();
StorageFolder Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
Folder = await Folder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
StorageFile sf = await Folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.mp3");
PlayMusic.SetSource(await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), sf.ContentType);
PlayMusic.Play();
```

Comment: `PlayMusic` does not exist in the current context, are you using a specific reference?

Comment: PlayMusic = new MediaElement();