# how to play a sound from .NetStandard 2.0 class library?

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-standard

The question heading explains the problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340353/play-sound-in-universal-windows-platform) answer seems to me to be the best option and what I want to do - play a .wav file. But I can't add the namespaces to use `MediaElement`. I want to play a beep/alert sound based on criteria met.

```
using Windows.Media.Playback;
using Windows.Media.Core;
```

Is there a .NetStandard2.0 Class Library alternative? I would like to avoid "third party", extra nuget packages.

Comment: I doubt that `netstandard` has anything suitable, just because "play sound" ultimately means "use native api to interact with sound device". Obviously, `netstandard` assemblies can't implement this functionality - it is platform dependent. What's the problem with `MediaElement`? Your question is tagged with "UWP", why don't use it?

Comment: my logic is within my `netstandard` library, and the `viewmodel` class(uwp) is not always in memory to handle whenever the criteria is met

Comment: Well obviously they *can* implement the functionality with appropriate OS-dependent wrappers, just like all other OS-dependent functionality already implemented (`Process` is just as platform-dependent). A platform-independent API for sound just happens to not be part of .NET Standard, or for that matter .NET Core. The most recent issue appears to be [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27450).

Comment: Declare some kind of `ISoundService` in `netstandard` assembly, and implement it inside UWP assembly. Use any platform-depended features you need inside implementation. Inject UWP implementation of `ISoundService` at run-time.

Comment: I'd investigate the NAudio library: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio - that basically wraps a number of different APIs depending on what it actually gets installed against, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the best route for an "intermediate" coder like myself. Thanks @JonSkeet

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use UWP APIs in your .Net Standard 2.0 class library project. Right-click your class library name and select **Add -> Project Reference…** option, click the **Browse** button on the **Reference Manager** dialog. Find the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd` and add the file. Find the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.18362.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\8.0.0.0\ Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd` and add it.